# Python: Extracting parameters of f-String from a log

Tags: python-3.x, parameters, f-string

I have an log-file with some written f-strings. Now I want to get the parameters again and save them in a dictionary.

e.g. I have the following log:

```
The following data is received: Name: Kreijeck, age=35, country=Germany
```

from this method:

```
def create_fstring():
    name = "Kreijeck"
    age = "35"
    country = "Germany"

    print(f"The following data is received: Name: {name}, age={age}, country={country}")
```

Now I want to create a Method that can extract the parameters again:

```
def get_key_value_pairs(f_string, log_string) -> dict:
    ### PSEUDOCODE ###
    d = f_string.extract_parametes(log_string)
    return d
```

where d shall be:

```
d = {
    'name': "Kreijeck",
    'age': 35,
    'country': 'Germany',
    }
```

when the input is the correct f_string

```
    f_string  = "The following data is received: Name: {name}, age={age}, country={country}"
```

Comment: Either use something like regex or just use basic string splits over and over again, e.g split at Name:, at age=, .... or even better: use a proper structured data exchange format, e.g. json.

Comment: Thanks @luk2302,
than I will try to use groups from regular expressions here: